# Is there a cleaner way to define my copy ctor with a mutex?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a POD struct like so

```
struct foo {
  std::mutex m_foo_mutex;
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  //......
};
```

It has more fields than this but the structure should be apparent. The default copy ctor is, of course, ill formed because `std::mutex`'s copy ctor is `delete`.

It's perfectly fine for my uses to copy this object, and give the copied object a new mutex. So I have defined something like this inside `foo`.

```
foo(const foo &foo2) : m_foo_mutex() {
a = foo2.a;
b = foo2.b;
c = foo2.c;
//.......
}
```

That's all well but it's quite ugly when this struct has 20+ fields, normally the compiler would hide this from me. Is there a cleaner way to express this, or am I stuck with this big ugly constructor?

Comment: why cant you split your class into _unsafe (POD) and safe {mutex + pod)?

Comment: I might be unclear on what you mean - but wouldn't the safe class still have this problem? Or do you mean the safe class would be un-copyable and the _unsafe one would not have a mutex?

Comment: That struct is _not_ a POD!

Comment: Your example does not look like usual. Ususally we make  mutex member mutable and lock the mutex of source object in copy constructor for to achieve that no other thread races to write it at time of copy. So compiler can't generate it anyway.

Comment: The problem you're having is a signal of a design flaw.

Comment: @brenzo the pain point is enumerating and copying the members, you create a POD unsafe struct that is copyable by default, and initialize it as part of the member initialization list to the safe class's copy constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap just your mutex in a copyable class:

```
struct CopyableMutex {
    std::mutex mutex;

    CopyableMutex() = default;
    CopyableMutex(const CopyableMutex&) {}
    CopyableMutex& operator= (const CopyableMutex&) {
        return *this;
    }
};

struct foo {
  CopyableMutex m_foo_mutex;
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

You might want to come up with a better name than `CopyableMutex` though, as obviously it isn't actually copying the mutex!

Comment: Good of you to leave the hard part to the OP. ;-)